# Python stochastic matrix

Tags: python, numpy, stochastic

I am trying to create a function that checks if a matrix and a vector are stochastic (sum of elements =1 for all the column both of the matrix and of course of the vector) if yes it applies matrix product between M and p otherwise raises an error. I created a function called  **is_sto** to verify sum=1 for vectors.
I tried something that is not working... I am a little bit skeptical about the triple **AND** but I couldn't do better. Is it possible to have a hint?
Many thanks

```
p=np.array([[0.5],[0.5]])
M=np.array([[0.3,0.5], [0.7,0.5]])
b=np.zeros(2)

def matrix_stoch (p,M):
   
 for column in M.T:
   
   b[None,:]=is_sto(column)
    
v= (b[0] and b[1] and is_sto(p))

if v == True:
       np.dot(M,p)
else:
      raise ValueError('no stochastic matrix')
```

Answer (score 0):

v is equivalent to:

```
all(sum(row) == 1 for row in M.T) and sum(float(elt) for elt in p) == 1
```

`sum(row)==1 for row in M.T` returns a list of length your number of columns, with the element True at position i if the sum of i-th column is one.

all is a built-in python function that checks if all the elements of a list are True. If it is the case, it returns True. Here it returns True if and only if all your columns are of sum 1.

Also, you check `if v == True:`. You can simply write `if v:`, it is simplier ;)

```
def matrix_sto(p,M):
    if all(sum(row) == 1 for row in M.T) and sum(float(elt) for elt in p) == 1:
        np.dot(M,p)
    else:
        raise ValueError('no stochastic matrix')
```

if you want an easier solution, you could have written:

```
import numpy as np

def matrix_sto(p,M):
    bool = True
    for row in M.T:
        bool = bool and sum(row) == 1
    
    sum_vector=0
    for elt in p:
        sum_vector += float(elt)
    bool = bool and sum_vector == 1
    if bool:
        np.dot(M,p)
    else:
        raise ValueError('no stochastic matrix')
```

Moreover, I think you need to put a return somewhere ;)

If you want the result of `np.dot(M,p)`, change it by `return np.dot(M,p)`

Comment: `sum(row) == 1 for row in M.T` is a generator expression there and does not return a list

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with the function you have written -

1. **The indentation in your code is incorrect and it puts the code after `v` outside the function** (I am hoping that you have just made a copy-paste error in Stackoverflow). This makes the b vector always set to `[0,0]` because the operations you are doing inside the functions have a different scope as they are local variables to the function. This therefore always returns the `ValueError`
2. There is a logic error in the step `b[None,:]=is_sto(column)`. **This sets BOTH the values `b[0] and b[1]` to `[1,1]` for EACH COLUMN of `M.T`**. I highly doubt you are trying to do that as it makes no sense. I believe what you want is to get `b[0] = 1` for first column and `b[1] = 1` for second column.
3. There is no `return` for the `no.dot` in your code.

I would recommend using the following code that makes the whole problem much simpler and free of errors. This eliminates the vector b from the picture as well and thus the faulty boolean indexing.

```
p=np.array([[0.5],[0.5]])
M=np.array([[0.3,0.5], [0.7,0.5]])

def is_sto(arr):
    return np.sum(arr)==1

def matrix_stoch(p,M):
    M_sto = [is_sto(i) for i in M.T]
    p_sto = is_sto(p)

    print('Stochastic check on columns of M: ', M_sto)
    print('Stochastic check on vector p: ', p_sto)

    if all(M_sto) and p_sto:
        return np.dot(M,p)
    else:
        raise ValueError('no stochastic matrix')

matrix_stoch(p,M)
```

```
Stochastic check on columns of M:  [True, True]
Stochastic check on vector p:  True

array([[0.4],
       [0.6]])
```

Comment: Many thanks this helps

Comment: Glad to help. Feel free to mark and upvote the answer if it helped!